# Design a TotalCost Calculator for a Shopping Cart

Tags: oop, design-patterns

This was asked of me at an Interview and feedback I got was I lack OOD skills. So I want to know what is wrong with my suggested design.

**Problem Statement:**
Design a system which helps calculate the TotalCost of the items in the Cart.
You will be given a list of items in the Cart with Discounts like in the example below. The list would contain either items or discounts and the sequence matters:

**Sample cart:**
$10 Book xyz, 10% Discount on all items, $20 stationary, 20% discount on next item, $100 Shirt, $15 off on 5th Item of Type Book.

**Types of Discounts:**
10% Discount on all items
20% discount on next item
$15 off on 5th Item of Type Book
(More type of Discounts can be added later to the system)

**Solution I gave:**

Here is the Class Diagram I made:
 [image: Class Diagram]

**Here is the TotalCost() Algorithm:**

```
public decimal TotalCost(List<CartItem> cartItems)
{
var totalCost =0.0;
var items = cartItems.where(c => c.Item!=null).Select(c.Item);
    foreach(var cartItem in cartItems)
    {
        if(cartItem.Coupon != Null)
        {
            cartItem.CouponType.CalculateDiscounts(items);
        }       
    }

    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        totalCost += item.DiscountedCost;
    }

    return totalCost;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The list would contain either items or discounts and the sequence matters

It's not clear from your design how you've catered for this part of the problem. I'm wondering if the problem is hinting at polymorphism combined with the sequential processing? Something like a `Composite` or `Strategy` design pattern might've been what they were looking for?

Comment: That is why I have a CartItem which contains a Doscount and a Actual Product Item and in a CartItem either Discount will be Not Null or Item would be Not Null. Are you saying I should have a CartItemBase and then then 2 child classes like CartItemDiscount and CartItemProduct?

Comment: Something like that. With the `Composite` pattern you would just iterate over the list in sequence asking the item, via an abstraction, for its cost. It's just one way of doing that leans on some of the features of OO. Also, where's your provision for '$15 off on 5th Item of Type Book'? Whatever's iterating needs to know the sequence and its current position in that sequence. This is where a `Strategy` might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the main flaw in your solution is the fact that your item class is aggregating the discount class. I think that whoever looked at your solution didn't continue pass that point.

The aggregation of discount (coupon) by item suggests that an item could have only one discount, and in your situation it is not the case. Having a list of coupons would not benefit either, since they did put out that a cart holds a list that **would contain either items or discounts**. Which usually suggests polymorphism and a base (super) type.

They probably looked for a solution that looks more or less like the following:

Class hierarchy -

```
interface CartItem {
}

interface Product extends CartItem {
    public int price();
    public void updatePrice(int updatedPrice);
}

interface Discount extends CartItem {
    public void applyDiscount(List<CartItem> cartItems);
}
```

Algorithm -

```
List<CartItem> cartItems = cart.getItems();
List<Discount> discounts = extractDiscountsFromItems(cartItems);
applyDiscountsOnCartItems(discounts, cartItems);
List<Products> discountProducts = extractProductsFromItems(cartItems);
int totalAmount = calculateAmount(discountProducts);
return totalAmount;
```

In languages that don't support filtering a collection you can use the Visitor pattern to filter out items.